# Can't use WP_Query() to loop through posts bbPress

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

The following does not work right out of the box and the page takes forever to load, it creates a lot of Apache processes  and consumes memory and CPU like crazy

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Custom forum index
 */

get_header();


?>
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php //do_action( 'bbp_template_notices' ); ?>

                <?php
                $args = array(
                   'post_type' => 'forum',
                   'post_status' => 'publish',
                   //'meta_key' => 'age',
                   'orderby' => 'title',
                   'order' => 'ASC',
                   // 'meta_query' => array(
                        // array(
                           // 'key' => '_bbp_topic_count'
                        // ),
                        // array(
                            // 'key' => '_bbp_reply_count'
                        // ),
                        // array(
                            // 'key' => '_bbp_last_active_time'
                        // ),
                        // array(
                            // 'key' => '_bbp_last_topic_id'
                        // )
                    // )
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);

                while ($query->have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div id="forum-front" class="bbp-forum-front">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <div class="entry-content">

                            <?php //the_content(); ?>

                            <?php //bbp_get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-forum' ); ?>

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #forum-front -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The underlying motivation is that that I'm trying to create a custom forum index page on which forums are laid out alphabetically based on their names. Strangely, such functionality does not come with bbPress

As you see above, I attempted to use WP_Query() to loop through the post with type "forum".
What could have gone wrong with such approach?
What do I need to do use to WP_Query() here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was wrong is `the_post()`. It should be `$query->the_post()`; instead.

So the correct loop would be

```
<?php  
//...  
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                <div id="forum-front" class="bbp-forum-front">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <div class="entry-content">

                        <?php //the_content(); ?>

                        <?php //bbp_get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-forum' ); ?>

                    </div>
                </div><!-- #forum-front -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of use of custom `WP_Query`, you need to specify `wp_reset_query();` after your `endwhile;` keyword. According the Wordpress documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query), "*This function destroys the previous query used on a custom Loop. Function should be called after The Loop to ensure conditional tags work as expected.*"

Comment: Thanks but no, it doesn't work @bodi0. The script still goes crazy, opens up a lot of Apache processes and kill both my memory and CPU

Comment: My understanding is that you only have to do a wp_reset_query after using query_posts() - but if you create a new WP_Query object, you shouldn't have to.